# error TS2769: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I've been following the instructions of setting up an application https://github.com/IBM/cognitive-social-crm, and run on the ubuntu of Windows Subsystem for Linux, but at the point where I'm trying to run the app locally with npm run start, I'm getting this error.

```
/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261
[1]     return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
[1]            ^
[1] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
[1] src/util/EnrichmentPipeline.ts(75,34): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
[1]   Overload 1 of 2, '(o: {}): string[]', gave the following error.
[1]     Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
[1]   Overload 2 of 2, '(o: object): string[]', gave the following error.
[1]     Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
[1] src/util/EnrichmentPipeline.ts(75,59): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
[1]   Overload 1 of 2, '(o: {}): string[]', gave the following error.
[1]     Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
[1]   Overload 2 of 2, '(o: object): string[]', gave the following error.
[1]     Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
[1]
[1]     at createTSError (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:261:12)
[1]     at getOutput (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:367:40)
[1]     at Object.compile (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:558:11)
[1]     at Module.m._compile (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:43)
[1]     at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
[1]     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
[1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
[1]     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
[1]     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/src/index.ts:13:1)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
[1]     at Module.m._compile (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
[1]     at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
[1]     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/cjycathy/cognitive-social-crm/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
```

part of the EnrichmentPipeline.ts:

```
public enrich(text: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const enrichmentPromises = [
          this.nluEnrichment(text),
          this.toneEnrichment(text),
          this.conversationEnrichment(text),
        ];
        Promise.all(enrichmentPromises).then((enrichments) => {
          const response: { [index: string]: any } = {};
          for (const e of enrichments) {
            const ets = e as { [index: string]: any };
            response[Object.keys(e)[0]] = ets[Object.keys(e)[0]]; #line 75 error occurs at here
          }
          resolve(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Any help is very much appreciated!